# How to set a filter as default filter in odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

i'm using odoo 11 and i want to set a default filter which group by employee. i made a modification on the module but it doesn't shows the right result(i want to remove the administrator filter) .I don't know what's the problem .Any idea for help please ?

[image].

```
<record id="action_bt_overtime_management" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Overtime</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">bt.hr.overtime</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="context">{'search_default_employee_id':1}</field>
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="bt_overtime_management_search"/>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                    Create Overtime Request
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give like this

```
<record id="action_bt_overtime_management" model="ir.actions.act_window">
                <field name="name">Overtime</field>
                <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
                <field name="res_model">bt.hr.overtime</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
                <field name="context">{'group_by':'employee_id'}</field>
                <field name="search_view_id" ref="bt_overtime_management_search"/>
                <field name="help" type="html">
                    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                        Create Overtime Request
                    </p>
                </field>
            </record>
```